# Specify the Jest Test Directory in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, configuration-files

I'm using the `jest-test-explorer` with the `test-explorer-ui` extensions in VS Code and have a directory `unit tests/` and another `acceptance tests/`. The test explorer sidebar shows and runs the tests in both directories however I would only want to see and run the tests in the `unit tests/` directory.

I use the `./node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage 'unit tests/'` command from the bash prompt to run the tests in the correct directory but what is the equivalent way to configure jest so that this becomes the default? I have a `jest-test.config.js` file containing the following:

```js
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'test',
    verbose: true,
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 0,
            functions: 0,
            lines: 0,
            statements: 0
        }
    },
    testMatch: [
        '**/unit\ tests/**/*.js'
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/__tests__/fixtures/',
    ]
}
```

When I run the command `./node_modules/.bin/jest` this still includes the second directory of tests and the sidebar still shows the other tests. How do I configure Jest to only look in the specified directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest "/unit tests"
```